# Find which 5 variables are most correlated with response

Tags: r, variables, linear-regression, correlation

I have a dataset "insurance" which contains 22 variables on medical expenditure data. I have to find which 5 variables are most correlated with the variable: "totexp".
I have tried cor(insurance$totexp,insurance) but it just gives me the correlations without sorting them. then I tried sort(cor(insurance$totexp,insurance)) and it shows the correlations sorted but it doesn't show the names of the variables.

Do you know what's the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cors <- cor(insurance$totexp,insurance) ; cors[, order(cors[1, ])]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cors <- cor(mtcars$mpg, mtcars)
cors[, order(cors[1, ])]
```

Returns:

> ```
>         wt        cyl       disp         hp       carb       qsec       gear         am         vs       drat        mpg 
> -0.8676594 -0.8521620 -0.8475514 -0.7761684 -0.5509251  0.4186840  0.4802848  0.5998324  0.6640389  0.6811719  1.0000000
> ```

We can use

```
cors[, order(cors[1, ], decreasing = TRUE)]
```

For the decreasing ordering...